# How can I make a material that looks like the 3D view?

Tags: texturing, materials

I would like to make a material that has different shades but only employs spot colours. I want different faces to be different shades based on how much light they get, but no gradients. Like in the 3D view:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That is a plain diffuse grey, there is nothing remarkable about it. Gradients are created by lighting and the render engine used, which you never mention. If you are using Cycles no amount of tweaking will yield that result and it is a waste of resources, just screen capture the viewport instead